# How can you vote to close a question after it's already been closed by a mod?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

If you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6590902/673730), you'll see that it's been closed by BoltClock♦, and afterwards SLaks appears to have also voted to close. I thought once a mod closes a question, that should be enough. Right?

Comment: He was not always a moderator...

Comment: More importantly, why isn't ceejayoz's name linked to his profile?

Comment: While I think that Flimzy and animunson have it, I'll note that you do (or at least did) very occassionally see closures attributed to six names which I believe is a sign of ungaurded asyncronous behavior. Presumably (if this situation still exists) the same could happen with a moderator driven closing.

Comment: It happens. Deal with it. Move on.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Wow, that's incredibly bizarre.

Comment: @bill-  ceejayoz probably deleted his account. The name is still displayed on closures and deletions.  For example, on Programmers Mark Trapp still shows on many closed questions even though his posts show User8.

Comment: @jmort253 - But ceejayoz is also the person answering the question, and  he is still linked in the answer. (Supposing there has not been two user with that name).

Comment: Good point, @BoPersson. I have no idea... :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That means the mod voted to close it before he was a mod.

Comment: ah, good point :)

Comment: Now I feel bad for asking...

Comment: This. It was closed in July 2011, BoltClock was made a moderator in November of 2011.

Comment: In this case it was actually two mods. SLaks is a retired moderator.